# For each function not showing label in array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, find, each

I have a variable containing labels/checkboxes and looping through the variable to populate an array, however, it is not including my labels when I push the values to the array.

My code is:

```
 posts = $('<div>
            <label for="q1_chk_0"><input id="q1_chk_0" type="checkbox" name="Country[]" value="DZA">Algeria</label>
            <label for="q1_chk_1"><input id="q1_chk_1" type="checkbox" name="Country[]" value="ARG">Argentina</label>
            <label for="q1_chk_2"><input id="q1_chk_2" type="checkbox" name="Country[]" value="ARM">Armenia</label>
            <label for="q1_chk_3"><input id="q1_chk_3" type="checkbox" name="Country[]" value="AUS">Australia</label>
            <label for="q1_chk_4"><input id="q1_chk_4" type="checkbox" name="Country[]" value="AUT">Austria</label></div>'); 


 $postsList = posts;

 $postsList.find('label').each(function(){

      postsArr.push($(this).html());
 });

 console.log(postsArr);  // The array contains all the input fields, but no labels on any of them
```

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mfeUR/

The end result I want to achieve is to loop through this array and then display the checkboxes with its appropriate labels.

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: I can see the labels on the jsfiddle.

Comment: @jarz when I view the result panel and do an inspect on the html, i don't see the labels. I also don't see them in the console.log(postsArr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) on the element.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nm3X/)

```
$postsList.find('label').each(function(){
    postsArr.push($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: that seems to have work. Just another quick question, if I remove the <div></div> tags from the variable posts, do you know why it won't work anymore? Is there a workaround for this?  Why do i have to surround it by div tags.

Comment: @MoxieC I'm pretty sure it's because you are using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which selects the descendants of an element. In this instance, if you were to remove the parent, `div` there wouldn't be any descendants to find.

Comment: @MoxieC As for an alternative, just use `filter()`. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/z2jCX/

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfeUR/2/)

Using code like this is more readable in my point of view :

```
div = $('<div class="third"></div>');
div.append(postsArr[i]);
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work. It removes the checkboxes completely.

Comment: sorry i badly understand the question i work on this :)